# Placing two similarly charged particles in space

Tags: energy-conservation, work

Now, I will make a hypothetical situation. Assume that we place two similarly charged particles (lets take electrons) in space. Imagine that there is no other force acting on the particles except the repulsive force and the gravitational force of the particles. In other words, only these two electrons are present in the universe. So they are free from any outside interference. Now by nature, these electrons will start moving away from each other due to the repulsive force. Since there is nothing to stop them (gravitational force will only slow them down and not stop them as it is of a lesser magnitude than the repulsive force) they will keep moving and never stop. Over here we exclude expansion of space also for no complications. Now since the particles will keep moving as there is a constant repulsive force acting on them, they will do infinite work because $Work = Force * displacement$ and the displacement over here will keep increasing. Please tell me what is the problem in my thought experiment because it violates conservation of energy.

Comment: Its the transformation of electrostatic energy into mechanical energy you are describing. The energy for a given configuration is $E=\frac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon r^2}$. This energy will be used to repel each other and do the work.

Comment: The displacement tends to infinite, but the force tends to 0. To get the whole work you'll have to calculate the integral $W = \int \vec F · d \vec x$. That will be a finite value.

Comment: The problem is that the Force is not constant during this process, so you _can't_ just do $Force*displacements$. In fact, if the force is not constant, what of its various values will you take?

Comment: @rodrigo but the force will never become zero and still the displacement will keep on increasing. And just another thing, how will you calculate the work even using calculus. The value of force will constantly change, won't it? And the velocity of the particles will keep increasing. Because, suppose after one second the particles experience a repulsive force of 1N. They will attain a certain velocity. Now after 2 seconds they have $x$ velocity but the repulsive force still acts thereby increasing the velocity further. Won't this also lead to an ever increasing velocity?

Comment: @rahulgarg12342: [That's the beauty of infinitesimals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno's_paradoxes#Achilles_and_the_tortoise). The computation is not so difficult, actually.

Comment: But then does this make it a paradox? And after a certain point won't the displacement become less than the planck length?

Comment: @rahulgarg12342: Planck length? If you enter Quantum Mechanics into this issue, then high school calculus will not be enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so we all agree that $W = \vec F · \vec x$. If the force varies, then the total work on each electron is calculated using an integral:

> $W = \int_{x_0}^\infty\vec F · d \vec x$

Here, $W$ is work, $\vec F$ is the electrical force, $\vec x$ is the distance of the charge from the center of your universe, and $x_0$ is the starting point from where you begin the experiment.

And the electrical force between the electrons is :

> $F = q {e_1 e_2 \over (2x)^2}$

$q$ is the Coulomb constant, $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the charges (they are equal), and $2x$ is the distance between them. You know, one $x$ to the left and one $x$ to the right. And since the force and the displacement are colinear we can omit the arrows.

Now we can solve the integral:

> $W = \int_{x_0}^\infty q {e_1 e_2 \over (2x)^2} dx$
>
> $W = {q e_1 e_2 \over 4 }\int_{x_0}^\infty {1 \over x^2} dx$
>
> $W = {q e_1 e_2 \over 4 } [{-1 \over x}]_{x_0}^\infty $
>
> $W = {q e_1 e_2 \over 4 } {1 \over x_0}$

And that is basically the formula for the eletric potential energy!

Comment: sorry as I do not understand calculus as of now since I am only 15. Can I please have a verbal explanation. And what is x0? And why have you taken $2x^2$?

Comment: @rahulgarg12342: Uf! Did you read my link to the [Zeno's (apparent) paradoxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno's_paradoxes#Achilles_and_the_tortoise). Basically, an infinite sum of ininitesimal values (almost zero) may result in a finite value. That's essenctially an integral.

Comment: I understand that as I already knew about the Zeno's Paradoxes. Sorry if I am frustrating you but honestly I just do not understand. Please can you just explain the first equation you made. Just tell me what each element means then I will be able to follow. Thanks.

Comment: @rahulgarg12342: You are welcome to ask, of course, but you question is difficult to answer without calculus, or at least, limits. That's why Zeno and friends struggled with these kind of paradoxes. I've added a few explanations of the terms in my equations.

Comment: I know limits. :). Do you mean delta x by dx?

Comment: $dx$ is a differential of $x$. Think of it as a limit of $\Delta x$ when $\Delta x \to 0$. And think of the $\int$ as a $\Sigma$ of infinite values.

Comment: Oh now I got it a bit. Though I still did not understand the last part of your answer. Anyways leave it. Thanks. Just tell me what are we limiting to infinity in your answer. Then I will get the basics of the problem which is good enough for me. And tell me practically, wasn't I right. Even calculus is still the best possible answer but not the exact answer. Do you agree? It is just the best answer we can reach but in reality it will differ a bit, right?

Comment: Calculus is exact as long as your problem is classic electrodynamics. But as you probably know, real world is not classic ED. But then, real world is not just 2 electrons either.

Answer (score 0):

as they move farther apart,, the magnitude of potential energy of the system reduces(which is 0 at infinity and infinity at 0 seperation in terms of magnitude),,, and the kinetic energy increases(which in this case tends to a specific value at infinity given by (2q1q2/4.pi.e)rm)^(1/2) where r is initial seperation
),, so the sum is conserved,, which means energy is conserved,,, hence , no it does not violate the principle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not so simple. In fact I think the final kinetic energy of the electrons is not equal to the initial potential energy. But this not means the energy conservation is violated. A moving charge that accelerate emits electromagnetic waves. This waves transport energy so the electron slows down while moving to infinity. The final total energy is:

$E_{final} =  E_{waves} = \frac{e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 x_0} = E_{initial}$

So there is no kinetic energy at infinity since, due to the self force (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force), the electron stops after some time.

Comment: You see, it can slow down at infinity but will not stop at infinity. It will still keep on moving and emitting waves though of a lesser and lesser energy.